# Using a handler class to create objects, how can I directly call methods on objects?

Tags: java

I'm making a very simple rhythm game in Java, where I want the player to time a button press with a "Beat" which moves along the screen towards a stationary player.

Objects are instantiated using a handler class, and so the objects don't have names which I can call a method on, which isn't really a problem for player as I only intend for there to be one player, but I need to compare the position of several beats moving down the screen to the player to award points, but I'm not sure how I can assign names to the beats created or any other way of calling a method directly for them.

```
handler.addObject(new Beat(1000,300,ID.Beat));
handler.addObject(new Player(100,300,ID.Player));
```

Handler Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

//Handler class is responsible for updating and rendering all game objects
public class Handler {

    LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

    public void tick(){
        //loops through every object
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            // sets temp object to linked list function which gets the ID of the current object
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.tick();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        //renders every object
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            //renders the temp object
            tempObject.render(g);
        }
    }

    public void addObject(GameObject object){
        //linked list built in method to add an object
        this.object.add(object);
    }

    public void removeObject(GameObject object){
        //linked list built in method
        this.object.remove(object);
    }
}
```

The game object class referred to is just a class with a couple positional variables, velocity etc, another tick and render method and other than that it is just getters and setters.

Comment: 1. what is the `handler`, how is it defined? Does it have any getters. 2. Can't you just assign the new `Player` to a variable and *then* add it to the handler, i.e. use both?

Comment: Please show code as text, not images. Also show a [mcve] of the class definitions

Comment: Sorry for vagueness, handler class creates a linked list for each object then has a couple methods for adding a new object, removing them and for rendering graphics and looping through each object, I'll edit the post with code too and answer the rest there

Comment: If there is only one player, then why would a player need to be part of a linked list?

Comment: All the objects in the game are part of the list, and player extends GameObject

Comment: Right, but you can store a singular player outside of the list.

Comment: There are a few methods which loop through all the game objects for consistent rendering and such, so I think it would be best to leave the player in there, I'd like to try add 2 player support at some point too.

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't just keep the `Player` in a field somewhere **in addition** to adding it to the `handler`.

Comment: not sure how that would help? sorry if I'm missing the obvious here

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to either pre-define the objects

```
Beat b = new Beat(...);
b.foobar()
handler.addObject(b);
```

> handler class creates a linked list for each object then has a couple methods for adding a new object

Or iterate them and check their types

```
for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
  GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

  if (tempObject instanceof Beat) {
    Beat b = (Beat) tempObject;
    b.foobar();
  }
}
```

Or do the same as you add them. Maybe even splitting certain types into individual lists.

```
public void addObject(Gameobject go) {
  if (go instanceof Beat) {
    Beat b = (Beat) go;
    b.foobar();
  }
  // add to list 
}
```

Or you can use method overloading

```
public void addObject(Beat b) {

}

public void addObject(Player p) {

}
```

Comment: Sorry just to check I've got this right, so for the second option, I need to loop through the game objects again, and where there are beats for example do some kind of for loop to assign them a name?

Comment: You are already iterating everything in the render function. Using a for loop is the same as an iterator. But using this example, you could render Beat objects in a different way; they don't necessarily need a "name". If that is what you want, you should add a `String name` attribute to the Beat class

Comment: I'm a bit stuck on the idea of a name to call the methods since I wanna avoid rewriting a lot, basically just need some way of knowing which object is which and comparing their positions.

Comment: 1) Knowing which object is which - that is what `instanceof` does. Casting aferwards allows you to call specific instance methods 2) Comparing their positions - Suggest you use an ArrayList rather than a LinkedList if you want to access list elements at any specific index.

Comment: My end goal with this is to have randomly generated beats until the player loses and I need to prevent them from being able to hit the same beat multiple times for example so they should be deleted if the player hits them or misses, so maybe an array list would be best not sure, unless there was some way I could specify the beat closest to the player like instanceof where x = something

Comment: If each beat has a coordinate, you just loop over each of them each tick and find the smallest distance